# RubyOnRails Rake test failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

i try to create internet shop from "Agile Web Development with Rails 4". When i write 'rake test', i get this message:

```
$ rake test
Run options: --seed 54737

# Running:

........F...F

Finished in 0.279167s, 46.5671 runs/s, 118.2088 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
ProductTest#test__product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title_-_i18n                 [/Users/roni/Coding/Ruby/depot/test/models/product_test.rb:82]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-["translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.messages.taken"]
+["has already been taken"]



  2) Failure:
ProductTest#test_product_price_must_be_positive     [/Users/roni/Coding/Ruby/depot/test/models/product_test.rb:25]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

13 runs, 33 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

It's product_test.rb

http://pastebin.com/1f5zkDwa

Please, help me, what i did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the location of error messages for the 'already taken' case has been changed in Rails 4 and the book must have missed this update.

The error message has been moved to the namespace where also other validation error messages of ActiveModel reside, to the `errors.messages`. Hence, the 'taken' error message was set under key `activerecord.errors.messages.taken`, but in Rails 4 it is under `errors.messages.taken`.

If you update line 82 in your test with the new key, the test should pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `errors.messages.taken` was the solution for me!

Answer (score 1):

Just like the message states, you don't have translation for `en.activerecord.errors.messages.taken` in `config/locales`.

Also, in `assert_equal` method, first argument is actual value, while second argument is expected value. So it should be:

```
assert_equal product.errors[:title], ["has already been taken"]
```

in this case.